# Worklight Simple Dialog Android prevent click outside

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, simpledialog

I am using WL.SimpleDialog.show() for showing messages. In my latest android version , if i am clicking outside the element, the Dialog box disappears. Could you please help how to fix this issue. If i am clicking outside , the dialog box should not disappear.

The worklight version is 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

6.1 is quite an old release by now. This may have been "fixed" AFAIK in later releases of MobileFirst. However have you good reasons to upgrade other than just the dialog - support for the upcoming iOS 10 and Android 7 is only from MobileFirst **6.3** and above.

Other than that there is no support for making the dialogs modal in previous releases, or customizing it with your own dialog.

In Android, dialogs are non-modal (you can discard them by tapping around the dialog).

Comment: Thanks Idan for the quick reply.